# What is the "images" module in the wx.richtext example?

Tags: wxpython

The RichText editor example [here](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/richtextctrl_overview.html) includes the line "import images", but I cannot find this library. I've tried the Python Image Library, but that does not appear to be correct because I get the error "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_rt_open'". Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you,
-david

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`images` is part of the wxPython demo and does nothing more than providing pre-canned images.

[Link to git-repo](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxPython/blob/master/demo/images.py)

You will have to try with your own `wx.Image`/`wx.Bitmap` instances to see what will work with `….writeImage(…)`.

Comment: Thank you for answering this question.